# Basic Geometry question about points

Tags: geometry

Can someone please explain how the following rotations are possible?

How to find all '?' ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using Matrix rotation**

The matrix of a rotation of angle $\pi/4$ is given by $$\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

**Using complexe**

The equation of a rotation of center $0$ is given by $$z'=z e^{i\pi/4}.$$

**By simply observe a draw**

I did the first case, the other are exactly the same. I made a mistakes, it's not the point $(0,3)$ but $(3,0)$. But it doesn't change the computation.
[image]

Comment: Can you please explain how you find that?

Comment: The matrix of an angle $\theta$ is simply given by $\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: So, in the example above, if we rotate the point (0,2) by π/4, what the new point will be?

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-\sqrt 2\\\sqrt 2\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 3):

If you want to rotate **anti-clockwise** through angle $\theta$ then the rotation matrix is
$$R = \begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta &-\sin\theta\\\sin \theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$

Now since $$\sin\frac{\pi}{4} = \cos\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$
We get that
$$R = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \begin{pmatrix}1 &-1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

To see what happend to $(3,0)$,

$$\begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\end{pmatrix} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \begin{pmatrix}1 &-1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}3\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 3):

The rotated axis are the main bissectors, two lines with equations $y=x$ and $y=-x$.

The point $(3,0)$ is three units away from the origin and remains so after rotation.

Expressing the squared distance, we have

$$x^2+y^2=3^2+0^2.$$

Combined to $x=y$,

$$2x^2=9,$$ so that the rotated point is $$\left(\dfrac3{\sqrt2},\dfrac3{\sqrt2}\right).$$ (There is another soution in the negatives, which is irrelevant.)

The other points can be handled similarly, with careful discussion of the signs.

---

**Generalization**:

The equation that expresses distance invariance can be written as

$$\left(\frac xd\right)^2+\left(\frac yd\right)^2=1,$$ and has the solution

$$x=d\cos(\theta),\\y=d\sin(\theta).$$

This represents the coordinates of a point on a circle of radius $d$, in the direction $\theta$ from the origin. If you want to rotate this point by an angle $\phi$, you will use

$$x'=d\cos(\theta+\phi),\\y'=d\sin(\theta+\phi).$$
By the angle addition formulas,

$$x'=d\cos(\theta+\phi)=d\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)-d\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)=x\cos(\phi)-y\sin(\phi),
\\y'=d\sin(\theta+\phi)=d\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)+d\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)=y\cos(\phi)+x\sin(\phi).$$

---

In the case of a $45°$ rotation,

$$x'=\frac{x-y}{\sqrt2},\\y'=\frac{y+x}{\sqrt2}.$$

And for the points initially on one of the axis,

$$x'=y'=\frac{x}{\sqrt2}$$
or
$$x'=-y'=-\frac{y}{\sqrt2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

A rotation about the plane is given by the $2 \times 2$ matrix
$$R(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Now you know you are rotating about $\pi/4$ so plug that in and the matrix $R|_{\pi/4}$ tells you how each point moves. Apply this to any$(x, y)$ gives new points $(x',y')$ where
$$\begin{bmatrix}
x' \\
y' \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
You should find that your $R(\frac{\pi}{4})$ agrees with the matrix found by Surb.